# YARN minimum-user-limit-percent not working?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm using the capacity scheduler in YARN and I saw that there's the possibility for users to get a minimum percentage of the queue by using the property 'yarn minimum-user-limit-percent'. I set this property to 20, and what I would expect is that resources would get equally distributed up to 5 users, according to this:

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/setting_user_limits.html

But that's not the case when users start runnig applications. For instance, if I run an application when the queue is idle, YARN allocates all the requested resources for that application. When another user runs the same application afterwards, YARN allocates as much resources as there are left in the queue, and the queue gets filled up. At this point, I thought that with the property the second user would get 50% of the queue, and the first one would have less resources.

If a third user comes in, I would expect him/her to get 33% of the queue, but YARN doesn't even schedule the application because there are no available resources left.

Am I missing something? I thought this parameter made requests independent of the available resources until it hit the minimum percentage per user.

Here are my yarn-site.xml and capacity-scheduler.xml:

- yarn-site.xml

  ```
  <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.admin.acl</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
      <value>hadoopLogin:8032</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
      <value>hadoopLogin:8033</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
      <value>hadoopLogin:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
      <value>hadoopLogin:8031</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
      <value>hadoopLogin:8088</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address</name>
      <value>hadoopLogin:8090</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.client.thread-count</name>
      <value>50</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.client.thread-count</name>
      <value>50</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.client.thread-count</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
      <value>1024</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb</name>
      <value>512</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
      <value>14336</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-vcores</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
      <value>32</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.amliveliness-monitor.interval-ms</name>
      <value>1000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.am.liveness-monitor.expiry-interval-ms</name>
      <value>600000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts</name>
      <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.container.liveness-monitor.interval-ms</name>
      <value>600000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.nm.liveness-monitor.interval-ms</name>
      <value>1000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.nm.liveness-monitor.expiry-interval-ms</name>
      <value>600000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.client.thread-count</name>
      <value>50</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name><value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler</value>
  ```

  yarn.scheduler.fair.user-as-default-queue
      true
    
    
      yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption
      false
    
    
      yarn.scheduler.fair.sizebasedweight
      false
    
    
      yarn.scheduler.fair.assignmultiple
      false
    
    
      yarn.resourcemanager.max-completed-applications
      10000
    
    
      yarn.nodemanager.aux-services
      spark_shuffle
    
    
      yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class
      org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService
- capacity-scheduler.xml

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues
       batch,notebook
       Definition of console and batch jobs (batch) and notebook jobs (notebook) queues

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.capacity
       50
       Percentage of capacity for root.batch queue

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.notebook.capacity
       50
       Percentage of capacity for root.notebook queue

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.maximum-capacity
      55
      Percentage of maximum capacity for root.batch queue

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.notebook.maximum-capacity
      55
      Percentage of maximum capacity for root.notebook queue

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.state
        RUNNING
        Current state of the root.batch cue

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.notebook.state
       RUNNING
       Current state of the root.notebook cue

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_submit_applications
       hadoop,yarn,mapred,hdfs,spark
       The ACL of who can submit jobs to the root queue.

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.acl_submit_applications
       scienceUser1 root,gaia,ub,ucm,uac,udc,esac,upo,une,inaf
       The ACL of who can submit jobs to the root.batch queue.

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.notebook.acl_submit_applications
       * root,gaia,ub,ucm,uac,udc,esac,upo,une,inaf
       The ACL of who can submit jobs to the root.notebook queue.

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.acl_administer_queue
       gaia
       The ACL of who can administer jobs to the root.batch queue.

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.notebook.acl_administer_queue
       gaia
       The ACL of who can administer jobs to the root.notebook queue.

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_administer_queue
       gaia
        The ACL of who can administer jobs on the root queue.

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_administer_queue
       gaia
        The ACL of who can administer jobs on the root queue.

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_administer_queue
       gaia
        The ACL of who can administer jobs on the root queue.

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.batch.acl_administer_queue
       gaia
        The ACL of who can administer jobs on the batch queue.

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.notebook.acl_administer_queue
       gaia
        The ACL of who can administer jobs on the notebook queue.

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator
       org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator

  yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.notebook.minimum-user-limit-percent
  33
   Minimum percentage of resources a user gets from the queue.

Comment: Please support Yarn configurations in detail. yarn-site.xml and capacity-schedule.xml

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not the way minimum-user-limit should be treated. suppose you have 100 GB and there are 4 users. As a fair , each can get up to 25GB. But what if tomorrow you have 100 users coming in? In such case, dividing equally will end up giving 1GB to each user. Now that is something we may not want to happen considering the case where each process will end up starving for resources and might lead to worse performance. So here we limit ourselves by specifying the parameter minimum-user-limit as 25%. Which means each user might get minimum 25GB and if there are more users , it will be put to accepted state.So now if 1 user comes in , it can go upto 100GB. 2 users can take upto 50GB each. 3 users can take upto 33 GB each , 4 users can take upto 25GB each. But if 5th user comes in. The 5th user will be send to waiting because each user cannot be given 20GB each because we have set the limit as 25%(of 100GB ) which is 25GB. P.S this is my understanding. If anyone finds that this is wrong , then please comment. It is indeed a bit confusing.
Now in your scenario , lets say first two users took the entire resources. That case is different from this. 25% limit only says that you can enter in only when you yarn has at least 25% available to allocate to you. For ensuring two users do  not take full resource , you can tweak with user-limit-factor. If set to .2 , each user cannot take more than 20%.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're seeing is correct if you haven't enabled preemption.
Look in your yarn-site.xml for `yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.monitor.enable` equals `true` to see if you've enabled it.

If you haven't enabled it, refer to the following for guidance:

- http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Capacity_Scheduler_container_preemption
- https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/preemption.html
- https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/89894/capacity-scheduler-preemption-doesnt-work.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer @tk421! I tried to enable container preemption by setting yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.monitor.enable to true but the behavior is still the same...I'm using hadoop 2.6.0 and I haven't seen container preemption in the capacity scheduler docs:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html

And yet they do mention yarn.scheduler.capacity..minimum-user-limit-percent....am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: I can't determine anything without seeing your config files.  Can you update your question with your yarn-site.xml and capacity-scheduler.xml?

Comment: Thanks again! I added both my yarn-site.xml and capacity-scheduler.xml files in the question.

Comment: You're still missing yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.monitor.enable = true in your yarn-site.xml in addition to all the preemption settings mentioned in https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/preemption.html.